# Change Range Slider Handle Color (On Click)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, rangeslider

```
<div id="slider">
    <br><span>0</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 3.3%">100</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 9.8%">300</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 16.4%">600</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 16.2%">900</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 15.7%">1200</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 13.3%">1500</span>
</div>
```

I am using default jquery range slider. When the handle is clicked, the handle head change into a blue one(As shown in picture). I am adding this raw html into wordpress theme. It works fine on local testing(without wordpress theme). Is there anyway to overwrite the color on click. Blue and my website theme doesn't go well.

Normal
[image: Normal]
On Click
[image: On Click]

Comment: have you tried inspecting the element in your debug panel of your browser? Most decent browsers will let you copy the CSS selector to your clipboard. Then you can use that to apply your background properties.

Comment: Can you paste the CSS that you used to render these? That way we can effectively tell you what you need to add and where. It sounds like the wordpress theme CSS is overriding whatever selector you have put in place for the handle. 

Try adding !important to the end of your css property declaration. Or try making the selector more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following pen:

https://codepen.io/barrychapman/pen/vmyjLR

Simply apply the `background-color` css property with `!important` to the selector:

```
#slider-range > span.ui-slider-handle:active {
    background-color: #0B0 !important;
}
```

And you should be good to go. Check the pen for results.

Answer (score 1):

Using devtools, you'll notice the CSS changes applied when you've clicked the handle. Just make note of the CSS line number when you've clicked and that rule is what you need to change. It is likely going to be this:

```css
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
a.ui-button:active,
.ui-button:active,
.ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
 border: 1px solid #000;/*changed this to black*/
 background: #000;/*changed this to black*/
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

If it gets overridden, then of course use higher selectors such as `body` at the beginning and `!important` as a last resort.

Comment: This will not accomplish what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Interesting, why would it not? Just tried it on your pen and it worked.

Comment: Because you are not targeting the handle of the slider.